# Octave 3D graphing with domain

Tags: plot, 3d, octave

I am trying to graph these two functions, but error appears when executing in octave.

```
ezplot3 ( (x.*y - x.^2*y)./(x - y),[0, 20],50);
error: ezplot3: F must be string, inline function, or function handle
error: called from
    __ezplot__ at line 143 column 5
    ezplot3 at line 62 column 19

ezplot3 ( log(x.^2 + y.^2 - 3) ,[0, 20],50);
error: ezplot3: F must be string, inline function, or function handle
error: called from
    __ezplot__ at line 143 column 5
    ezplot3 at line 62 column 19
```

Answer (score 1):

`ezplot3` plots a parametrically defined curve in three dimensions.

According to the `ezplot3` [function reference](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/ezplot3.html), the syntax is:

`ezplot3(fx,fy,fz)`

where `fx`, `fy` and `fz` are strings, inline functions, or function handles with **one argument** defining the function (e.g. `fx= @t cos(t)`).

In order to plot a function of two variables, I would suggest using `ezmesh`. For instance:

```
fx=@(x,y) (x.*y - x.^2*y)./(x - y)
ezmesh ( fx,[0, 20],50);
```

returns the following image:

[image]

Please let me know if this works for you!